# error with xlswrite in Matlab after connecting to the SAP2000 API

Tags: excel, matlab

I have written a code in MATLAB that do some analyses in SAP2000. Next, it tries to write some of the results in an excel (.xlsx) file using xlswrite command. 
 The problem is with writing the columns. What is written in the excel file is just a column of repeated first element of the array.
I make an example to explain my problem.

Before running the m file, which connects MATLAB with SAP2000, entering the code below

> > xlswrite ( 'My_File.xlsx' , [1;2;3;4] )

works fine and there is a column including numbers 1 to 4 starting from 'A1' cell in the file My_File.xlsx.
However, after running the m file, entering the exact code above gives me a column (4x1) of 1 s starting from 'A1' cell.

What is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a bunch of codes in accordance to the CSi API Documentation.
It's really driving me crazy.
All I can do is to save the Workspace, close and reopen MATLAB, then write the data into excel.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this problem? Is it common when the MATLAB connects to other softwares?

Comment: may be the code you use to connect to SAP200 messes up with the `xlswrite` function (do you have any `global` variable hanging around?). After running your SAP code, try running `clear xlswrite` before you use the `xlswrite` function.